# Files Being Placed in "Dist" Folder Are Mis-placed, Breaking the Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using a mockBackend as part of my Angular2 app, in order to test a login component I'm working on. I have a stand-alone version of the login working. But when I try and incorporate it into my already-in-development app I'm running into an issue. Specifically, it seems that in compilation some of my files are being placed into the "dist" folder in a way that makes it impossible for Angular to find them. Not sure why this is happening. Here's the error I see in my console:

```
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/testing 404 (Not Found)
```

Sure enough, when I look in my node_modules within my "dist" files, I see the "testing" folder is there, but it's not exactly where Angular's looking for it.

I had what I think is a similar issue a couple weeks ago with my socket.io "dist" location, and I had to manually adjust my systemjs.config.js file to point to the correct location. Then it worked. In this instance, is that what I need to do again? When there's a mis-location like this happening in the compilation to the "dist" folder, how should I best handle it?

By the way, I'm currently using Angular 2.0.0.

Here's what the contents of my systemjs.config.js looks like:

```
/**
 * SystemJS configuration file.
 */
(function(global)
{
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'dist',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            /*'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',*/
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            // 'socket.io-client': 'npm:/socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
            'socket.io-client': 'node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
            // 'socket.io-client': 'dist/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
            'angular2-chartjs': 'npm:angular2-chartjs',
            'chart.js': 'npm:chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
            rxjs: {defaultExtension: 'js'},
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
            'socket.io-client': {'defaultExtension': 'js'},
            'angular2-chartjs': {main: './dist/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });
})(this);
```

And here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "docs": "typedoc --experimentalDecorators --out docs/ app/ --target 'es5' -module 'system' --ignoreCompilerErrors",
    "clean": "del /q dist",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/main.min.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/main.min.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && browserify -s main dist/main.js > dist/main.min.js && npm run minify"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.1.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found a resolution. I had to manually add this line to my systemjs.config.js file:

'@angular/http/testing': `'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js'`

After that, everything worked as expected.